# ISSUE IN CASE STATEMENT VS CORRELATED QUERY (DB2 Coursera IBM Course)

Tags: nosql, db2

I am currently enrolled in the course by IBM on Coursera. I have written down two queries one with a sub query method and one with a case statement with correlated query.Answer of both looks same initially but is different in the values of other columns. Is the problem in my query?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` clause of the two queries is different, so it is not surprising that the order of the rows is different.

Comment: I have got my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that multiple values of `local_name` have the same value of `lang_num`.  That means that the sorting has ties.

The `order by` clause in SQL is not *stable*.  This has a technical meaning that running `order by` twice on the same data produces the same results -- even when keys have the same value.  The reason is simple:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no default ordering for rows that have the same key values.

The solution is easy.  Just make sure that the `order by`  keys uniquely identify each row:

```
order by lang_num, local_name
```